# Programming monitor that eliminates glares

Tags: monitors

I work in the corner of a sunny office, with four large windows close behind me. Normally it's fine but sometimes,  depending on the sun's position, unpleasant glare is visible on my screen (see photo below). That's especially annoying as I mostly use dark-themed IDEs for programming. I can close the blinds, but then I feel like I work in a basement.

I'm looking for a better display, and the glaring problem is my main criteria for choosing it. Since it's for the office, not gaming, I don't care about reaction time or refreshing rate.

My current monitor is 24" and I think 27" should be a bit better, but I don't think I need anything bigger. It would be nice if the monitor will be cheaper than 500$, but I can make an exception if it will be really good.

[image: photo showing glare]

Comment: I think you could buy any monitor with a strong light.

Comment: Well, I think that's not the only factor. I don't want to burn my eyes each time I switch for something with light background.

Comment: Eyes are very adaptive.

Comment: Actually, I fail to see how strong light from the monitor would help eliminate glares. Maybe I will see better what the monitor displays, but still will be annoyed by the glares. I think about maybe some anti-reflective coating?

Answer (score 1):

HP's 24" anti-glare monitor is available for [$197 in the US](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VFC787T), as is their [27" monitor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VFC787T), both well within your budget. The 24" is [€129](https://www.amazon.de/HP-Zoll-Full-Monitor-HDMI/dp/B07PN63WQ8/ref=sr_1_1_sspa) and the 27" monitor is [€159](https://www.amazon.de/HP-Zoll-Full-Monitor-HDMI/dp/B07PQGRN5Q/ref=sr_1_1_sspa) if bought close to you. Here's a [datasheet](https://content.etilize.com/Manufacturer-Brochure/1059541992.pdf).

Also, 3M makes [add-on non-glare filters](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/All-3M-Products/Privacy-Screen-Protectors/Protection-Products/Anti-Glare/?N=5002385%208710873%208711017%208725316%208725355%208725357%203294857497&rt=r3) you could add to your existing monitors in a variety of sizes, like this [24" widescreen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B017BCV184). So does Flexion; [here's a 24" version](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0126X39KG).

Comment: Please also see https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers